# How can a single sample represent the expectation in gradient temporal difference learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, math, deep-rl

I was reading the gradient temporal difference learning version 2(GTD2) from rich Sutton's book page-246. At some point, he expressed the whole expectation using a single sample from the environment. But how a single sample can represent the whole expectation.

I marked this point in this image.

[image]

Comment: This is just a simple SGD algorithm so one sample is enough.

Answer (score 2):

In the, presumably final, printed version the last two equal signs are approximations. This is just because over a large amount of weight updates where you have been sampling the expectation will be approximated by Monte Carlo.

Comment: What you mean by saying expectation will be approximated by Monte Carlo?

Comment: You can estimate an expectation by using Monte Carlo methods. An example would be if you had a Normal(0,1) distribution and took enough samples from it then the expectation of a random variable with that normal distribution would be approximated by the sample mean of all your samples. You can do this from any distribution you can sample from - in your example the samples come from repeated interaction with the environment.